# scala/lift jetty IntelliJ Idea: imported javascript files not showing changes in served page

Tags: linux, scala, intellij-idea, jetty, lift

I have never asked a forum question before so if I'm breaking a rule its unintentional and I'm sorry.

I have a webapp that I am making using scala/lift and jetty in the IntelliJ Idea IDE.  I have a javascript debug webapp that I designed for .net frame work although all I used the .net server for was to serve it because it runs strictly in in html and javascript.  I want to use my debug tool for pages that are served by the lift/scala/jetty server and I am currently porting it so that it will work on the new server.  The problem that I am having is that the html pages in my debug tool import external javascript files like so:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "jsFile.js"></script>
```

now this seemed to work at first but when I made changes to the src javascript file they were not happening in the page that was served by lift.  I verified this by following the link in the view page source page from the browser and it showed the version of the file before I added it into the project.  If I change the name of the file in the file system the IDE recognizes right away that it can't resolve the path to jsFile.js.  I have tried serving the pages through the site map as well as dumping my project in the /static directory.  I have restarted, browser,ide, server, os.  I have rebuilt the project, remade the module and have done a synchronize.  I have created a new project from scatch and ran into the same problem.  I believe that if I where to dynamically use lift to insert my javascript with JsRaw it would fix the problem but I still want to know why this isn't working in case its something that I'm doing wrong that will rear up bite me again someday.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In your template, try to enclose your  tags with the lift tag **with-resource-id**

like

```
<lift:with-resource-id> 
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "jsFile.js"></script>
</lift:with-resource-id>
```

If this does not solve the problem, are you using SBT to build your lift app? If this is the case, you can have one terminal running

```
~prepare-webapp
```

which basically watches for changes on scala files as well as html/css/js files and updates the running jetty (which has to be started by sbt as well running:

```
jetty-run
```

Comment: This worked I had to add xmlns:lift="http://liftweb.net/ to my html tag as well but I probably should have done that already anyway.  Thanks so much I was really stuck.